# ¿Enviar datos desde una aplicacion móvil a un servidor HTTPS garantiza cierta seguridad?

Tags: ajax, http, seguridad, app

Estoy creando una aplicacion móvil que tiene un sistema de login, utilizo javascript (AJAX) para enviar datos (realizar consultas) a un servidor web con PHP y que este me retorne respuestas.

Leí un post acerca de como encriptar los datos pero que al fin y al cabo no servía de nada por que de todas maneras los datos se podían interceptar y que era mejor tener HTTPS.

Por esto mi servidor web cuenta con HTTPS.

¿Esto garantiza cierta seguridad en el traspaso de datos entre este servidor y mi app?

Comment: ¿Qué tanto es "cierta" seguridad?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Si claro, HTTPS garantiza cifrado entre el cliente (Tu aplicación) y el servidor, entonces si existe algiuen quien intercepte el mensaje no podra entenderlo...Es importante que el Servidor esté configurado con certificados firmados...

Justamente eso es lo que hace HTTPS es el protocolo HTTP con seguridad SSL...Es el estandar adoptado por bancos, comercios electrónicos y otras entidades a nivel mundial para enviar mensajes....Es importante acotar, que usar solo HTTPS no garantiza que tu sistema sea seguro, esto es solo uno de los puntos que debes atacar en materia de seguridad, que en este caso evita ataques de hombres en el medio. Pero pueden haber otros tipos de ataques a parte de la capa de transporte.

Comment: Por favor agrega alguna fuente fiable o documentación que sustente lo que dices.